# Pipeline using multiple columns

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, feature-selection

I have a binary classification problem. My dataset consists of columns of different types: binary (0 or 1) or textual (text from emails). I have more than 40 columns.

An example may be the following:

```
Text                             is_it_capital?     is_it_upper?      contains_num?   Label
an example of text                      0                  0               0            0
ANOTHER example of text                 1                  1               0            1
What's happening?Let's talk at 5        1                  0               1            1
```

I am trying to use pipeline in order to make the prediction.
However, the fact I have already encoded some columns (is_it_capital?, ....) is not helping me a lot, as I do not know how to add these columns (features) in my pipeline. All of them are numerical and they take values either 1 or 0 (checked using `numerical_columns = train_set.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])`).

If I had not already encoded that columns, probably FeatureUnion would have been a good solution; in this case, I have no idea on how to proceed.

I have tried as follows

```
  nb_pipeline = Pipeline([
            ('NBCV',extract_func. tf_idf_n),
            ('nb_clf',MultinomialNB())])
    nb_pipeline.fit(train_set,train_set['Label']) # I am considering the whole training set
    predicted_nb = nb_pipeline.predict(test_set)
    np.mean(predicted_nb == test_set['Label'])
```

but I got the error

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [30, 4394]
```

I am splitting the dataset into train (80%) and test (20%) using `train_test_split`. `y` is only `Label`, while `X` contains all the other columns in my example. After splitting the dataset, I concatenate `X_train` and `y_train` as follows:

```
train_set= pd.concat([X_train, y_train], axis=1)
test_set = pd.concat([X_test, y_test], axis=1)
```

FULL TRACK OF ERROR:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-bab0cc0a9f07> in <module>
      6         ('nb_clf',MultinomialNB())])
      7 
----> 8 nb_pipeline.fit(train_set.drop('Label', axis=1), train_set['Label'])
      9 predicted_nb = nb_pipeline.predict(test_set.drop('Label', axis=1))
     10 np.mean(predicted_nb == test_set['Label'])

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    333             if self._final_estimator != 'passthrough':
    334                 fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
--> 335                 self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
    336 
    337         return self

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    613         self : object
    614         """
--> 615         X, y = self._check_X_y(X, y)
    616         _, n_features = X.shape
    617         self.n_features_ = n_features

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py in _check_X_y(self, X, y)
    478 
    479     def _check_X_y(self, X, y):
--> 480         return self._validate_data(X, y, accept_sparse='csr')
    481 
    482     def _update_class_log_prior(self, class_prior=None):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    430                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
    431             else:
--> 432                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    433             out = X, y
    434 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
    810         y = y.astype(np.float64)
    811 
--> 812     check_consistent_length(X, y)
    813 
    814     return X, y

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    254     if len(uniques) > 1:
    255         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 256                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    257 
    258 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [29, 4394]
```

Comment: Does `y_train` equal to `train_set['Labels']`? If yes, you shouldn't have concatenated `X_train` and `y_train` into `train_set` and passed into `nb_pipeline.fit`. Same for the test set. `fit` methods of scikit-learn estimators accept separate parameters `X` (samples) and `y` (labels). Try `nb_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)` and `nb_pipeline.predict(X_test)`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Sanjar. `y_train` is bigger than `train_set['Label']` as I had to apply resampling. If I used `train_set['Text']` and `train_set['Label']` within the pipeline, it would work. So the problem is in selecting more features to include. I already tried to use `nb_pipeline.fit(train_set, train_set['Label'])`  but I get that error. I am adding also this information on `train_set` and `X_train` to give more clarity on this.

Comment: Anyway, you cannot pass `train_set`, which also include labels `train_set['Label']`, into `fit` as training vectors and then `train_set['Label']` as labels. In your training set you should store only features or alternatively, drop labels during `fit`. Try  `fit(train_set.drop('Label', axis=1), train_set['Label'])` and `predict(test_set.drop('Label', axis=1)`. P.S. This doesn't seem to be an answer to your question though. I believe the error was caused by train-test set inconsistency.

Comment: I am getting the same error even after these changes. I looked at information on columns: I have the same number of rows in train_set so I would expect the `nb_pipeline.fit`  should work fine. I have not the same error if I use `train_set['Text']` (so only one column). Could you please explain me what you mean with train-test set inconsistency? Train set has approximately 4000 rows, while test has approximately 800 rows

Comment: Probably `ColumnTransformer` will be needed, if you plan on tfidf-encoding the text and then including the custom indicators.  I'm not sure if that could be the cause of the samples number mismatch.  Please provide the full error traceback, and some information about the different frames' shapes.

Comment: Thanks Ben Reiniger. I am not familiar with ColumnTransformer and I do not know where to apply it. Information about the shape: train: (4394, 30) and test: (826, 30) . Please see the updated question.

Comment: @LdM What is `extract_func.tf_idf_n`? Is it `CountVectorizer`? If yes, you need to encapsulate it in `ColumnTransformer` and pass the remaining features through untransformed. Same for `TfidfVectorizer` (note though that `MultinomialNB`, which runs after `tf_idf_n`, is expected to work with discrete data). Next, what is `resample`? Does it work as expected? Are you sure after concatenation of `not_spam` with `over` you do not get `NaN`s in `train_set`? Again, I'm not sure these questions resolve your issue but I believe they need to be taken into consideration first.

Comment: Thanks a log Sanjar! Yes, resample is for resampling data as I have a class imbalance. I removed from the original dataset all NaN values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the traceback, you can see that the tfidf transformer completes, and the NB model is what breaks.  I suspect the tfidf is not doing what you expect it to, because it is treating the entire frame as an iterable of *columns* to be encoded; so it thinks there are only 29 "documents", and so the NB sees 29 training rows with 4394 labels.

I believe something like the following should work the way you want it to.

```
ct = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[('tfidf', extract_func.tf_idf_n, 'Text')],
    remainder='passthrough',
)
nb_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('preproc', ct),
    ('nb_clf', MultinomialNB())
])
nb_pipeline.fit(train_set.drop('Label', axis=1), train_set['Label'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ben Reininger! Yes, I am not getting errors anymore using your proposed code. So, if I understood correctly, the `transformers=[('tfidf', extract_func.tf_idf_n, 'Text')]`, only works with Text column (I could change the pre-processing algorithm, for example use also Bag of Words instead of TF-IDF, and it should still work) and after Text is vectorised I apply the classifier. `train_set` in the pipeline should contain all the features (those ones from Text after applying the vectorisation + the other columns), shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, any text processor should drop in well.  You can check the output with `ct.transform(x_train)`, and `ct.get_feature_names()` should work to get the transformed feature names, in this case.  Also see Sanjar's comments, especially regarding the use of `MultinomialNB`.